# Android, Is it possible to consolidate two APK files?

Tags: android

I have a project for Android. In this project my client asked me following scenario but I'm not sure that it is possible.

They want to create an app-store for android. In this store after developer uploads his application we should wrap this APK file with our APK file (therefore we will have one APK file). This wrapper adds some activities to developer's application in order to able users to check their credits and add credits if they have not enough credit to their account (we don't want to manipulate the developer's code, we just want to add our code into their code). Therefore, when user download and install this application, each time he/she launches the application, our wrapper should be run first and check his/her financial account through Internet, if s/he has enough credit in his account, therefore s/he is free to use the application. If s/he didn't have enough credit we should guide him/her to buy more credit.

The things that I did, I created two sample project to see if I add APK of one to second, may I run that application from second application.

In the first application I just show some text in its activity and in second project (wrapper) I created a button that when I click on it, first project should be run. The result was not satisfactory and I couldn't run it.

I think if I export JAR file from first project and repeat above procedure I'll have better results but because in future we can't ask developers to put JAR file of your application instead of APK, it is not a good idea.

Now, for around a week I was thinking about this story and I couldn't find a way to know how can I consolidate and merge developer's application with our wrapper application.

If you have any suggestion please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get something along those lines is going to be as follows.

1. Setup a few permissions for accessing data from your "store" application. using these same permissions you can detect if any of these apps are installed on their phone.
2. Your going to want to make a ContentProvider that access the users account info and retrieves that information in your "store" application. Using this content provider you setup an api for accessing user information in the third party apps.

At this point you should have access to all users info (also use credit) and know if they have those applications installed.

Now for the third party apps

1. My suggestion make a jar file that uses the content provider. Also activities that do some basic stuff like making sure your store is installed and stuff. Bundle that app and have your 3rd party developers use it when making apps.
2. setup a sample application for using your jar and proper documentation. Very important always so hard when there isn't proper documentation on a jar file. But basically you should have static and helper classes for every aspect of interacting with the users account. And the application should only be asking for permission on using this information.

Here's a few content provider tutorials also a link for manifest settings to get the provider to work with permissions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/41133/1763/page/2
http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/content-provider-example-1.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#prmsn

One last thing if you don't want third party application appearing on a user normal launcher for some reason you can request that developers also not add CATEGORY_LAUNCHER to their main activity. In which case you will have to query for the main activity in your store application.

Comment: what if I have no control at all of the 3rd party apk files? I mean as in existing app that no longer modifiable, I'd still like to write a wrapper to prevent it from running...